# Get a List hierarchy using java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Manager` class that contains two Lists:

```
public final class Manager extends Worker // Worker is an implementation of Employee class
{
    private final List<Employee> subordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    //private final List<Employee> allSubordinates = ?
    //...
}
```

First one contains instances of `Employee`

```
public abstract class Employee extends Person
{
//...
public void setManager(Manager manager)
    {
        if(this.manager != null)
        {
            this.manager.getSubordinates().remove(this);
        }
        this.manager = manager;
        this.manager.getSubordinates().add(this);
    }
}
```

Each Manager is an Employee, thus have their own Manager (null if it's a hierarchy top). I want my second list to contain all the nested Employees in the hierarchy in addition to direct subordinates.

Comment: Rather than show an empty list, show a [mcve] with your complete inputs and expected outputs

Comment: with your current model, you can't because the subordinates of a manager are employees, and an employee doesn't have subordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this peace of code, and it seems to be doing the job.

```
private final List<Employee> subordinates = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<Employee> temp = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<Employee> allSubordinates = new ArrayList<>();

public List<Employee> getAllSubordinates()
{
    allSubordinates.clear();
    allSubordinates.addAll(subordinates);
    subordinates.stream()
        .filter(employee -> employee instanceof Manager)
        .map(employee -> ((Manager) employee).getAllSubordinates())
        .forEach(temp::addAll);
    allSubordinates.addAll(temp);
    temp.clear();
    return allSubordinates;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `temp` and `addAll`... This is what `flatMap` already does

Comment: And don’t keep objects for no purpose, like the `temp` and `allSubordinates`. This looks like esoteric optimization attempts, which are not only a source of bugs, but even decreasing performance in real life.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood the question, you want to `flatMap` each subordinates' list of subordinates

```
manager.getSubordinates().stream()
    .flatMap(Employee::getSubordinates)
    .collect(toList())
```

Comment: Are we assuming that a manager's subordinate's subordinate cannot have a subordinate?

Comment: Also, this logic filters out all the managers.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay 1) OP only wanted the second-level list. 2) There is no filter as we're starting from one manager. OP didn't ask for data from all managers